# C# If Else Statement Return Different MessageBox Errors

Tags: c#, forms, if-statement

I want to Show messages with `MessageBox.Show()` Method.

If txt_Phone.TextLength >= 3 AND dtp_StartDate.Value < dtp_EndDate.Value they do same thing. But I want to show different messages. For textlength I will show 'Enter more than 3 characters.'
For if startdate greater than stopdate I will show ' Start Date can not bigger than Stop Date'

```
 if (txt_Phone.TextLength >= 3 & dtp_StartDate.Value < dtp_EndDate.Value)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=ViasesTest;User Id=sa;Password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;");
                myConn.Open();
                SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetData", myConn);
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", dtp_StartDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", dtp_EndDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txt_Phone.Text.ToString().Trim());
                myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(myCmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hata!");
            }
```

Comment: Are you looking for `else if (...)`?

Comment: So, what is the big deal here? if..else if.. else..!!?

Comment: `&` is the binary and operator. Did you mean `&&`, the logical and operator?

Comment: "I want to show different messages" then you need to split your condition in 2 different if-clauses. and don't use else because it seems that both conditions can be true. Preferably you should construct only a message depending on the conditions and have a single `MessageBox.Show` call

Comment: @stickybit the [`&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-and-operator-) operator also works foor booleans, just not short-circuiting (meaning that both operands are always evaluated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below code snippet to get desired output -

```
if (txt_Phone.TextLength >= 3 )
{
    if ( dtp_StartDate.Value < dtp_EndDate.Value)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=ViasesTest;User Id=sa;Password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;");
        myConn.Open();
        SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetData", myConn);
        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", dtp_StartDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", dtp_EndDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txt_Phone.Text.ToString().Trim());
        myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(myCmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Start Date can not bigger than Stop Date");
    }
}
else
{
     MessageBox.Show("'Enter more than 3 characters");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that's what I needed.

Comment: @BatuhanBAKAR if this answer helped you, you should consider to mark it as accepted. How it can be done is [shown in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) happy coding